# why should we return a BOOL when I use -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield

I'm working on a small project and using several textField.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField{
if(textField.tag ==0){
    [self.PWText becomeFirstResponder];
    return false;
}else if(textField.tag ==1){
    [self.PWTextCheck becomeFirstResponder];
    return false;
}else if(textField.tag ==2){
    [self.nameText becomeFirstResponder];
    return false;
}else if(textField.tag ==3){
    [self.phoneText becomeFirstResponder];
    return false;
}else{
    [self.phoneText resignFirstResponder];
    return true;
}}
```

as I know I'll use this delegate method when I want to make the keyboard disappear when the user tap the "return" button on the keyboard.

no matter which one I returned there no difference as I seen from the simulator,
if I want to make the keyboard disappear I use :

> [... resignFirstResponder];

and when I want the keyboard focus on one of the textField I use:

> [... becomeFirstResponder];

but why should I return a True/False in this method?

Comment: yap  the same question and I saw the answer, thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

As the documentation states:

> The text field calls this method whenever the user taps the return
>   button. You can use this method to implement any custom behavior when
>   the button is tapped.

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn

So, if you want to do some sort of action when the user presses the return button, you can implement it here. This way you can perform the action **without** dismissing the keyboard for that textfield.

Comment: I saw an answer from the page Tore Olsean offered, and one of the answer said, if I want to use my own method I should return "false" ,if I returned YES, the delegate would use the default method~
and thank you for your answer :D